# DataTemplate don't change Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

```
<DataTemplate>
              <Image Name="ServerImageSetter" Source="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test1.svg}"/>
              <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ServerKindTrigger}" Value="0">
                      <Setter TargetName="ServerImageSetter" Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test2.svg}"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ServerKindTrigger}" Value="1">
                      <Setter TargetName="ServerImageSetter" Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test3.svg}"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
                  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ServerKindTrigger}" Value="2">
                      <Setter TargetName="ServerImageSetter" Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test3.svg}"/>
                  </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate
```

In my C# code I switch the kind of my value to 0-2 and that should change the image. But the change doesn't work.

```
 public int ServerKindTrigger
    {
        get { return _serverKindTrigger; }
        set { _serverKindTrigger = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }   

//Here I switch my serverkind and wanna change the image value 

switch (_serverKind)
        {
            case Servers.test: _serverKindTrigger = 0;
```

Comment: if you assign new value to variable `_serverKindTrigger`, you don't raise notification. do it via property: `ServerKindTrigger = 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides setting the backing field `_serverKindTrigger` instead of the property `ServerKindTrigger`, and thus not firing the PropertyChangedEvent, you are directly setting the Source property of the Image control:

```
<Image Source="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test1.svg}"/>
```

This so-called local value always has a higher precedence than the values from the Setters in the DataTriggers. For reference, see [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

Change your XAML to this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test1.svg}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ServerKindTrigger}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test2.svg}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ServerKindTrigger}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test3.svg}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ServerKindTrigger}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{svg2Xaml:SvgImage ServerAdministrator2;component/Images/test3.svg}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the solution! (:

Answer (score 0):

You are changing local fields and not the property, which is why it isn't triggering binding updates.

Change your switch/case assignment to assign ServerKindTrigger property.

```
switch (_serverKind)
        {
            case Servers.test: ServerKindTrigger = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but my problem is still alive. Where my image should be, there just stand "sys".